# I'm having sudden unauthorized/internal server errors

Tags: angular, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm creating this webpage in Angular with .NET as my backend. Everything was working just fine, but today (all of a sudden) I'm getting Unauthorized errors (401). When I remove my authorization, I'm getting internal server errors (meaning my 'User.Identity.Name') does not work. So I'm guessing there is a problem with my JWT

I have tried to remove authorization headers. But that gave me an internal server error (500). The only requests that work are those not using IdentityUser and thus being [AllowAnonymous]

I have no idea what the problem could be, so it's hard to show some code. But since I think the problem has something to do with my JWT I'll add some code of that.

```js
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public class BierenController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly IBierRepository _bierRepository;
            private readonly IGebruikerRepository _gebruikerRepository;
            private readonly IBrouwerRepository _brouwerRepository;

            public BierenController(IBierRepository bierRepository, IGebruikerRepository gebruikerRepository, IBrouwerRepository brouwerRepository)
            {
                _bierRepository = bierRepository;
                _gebruikerRepository = gebruikerRepository;
                _brouwerRepository = brouwerRepository;
            }


            [HttpGet]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            public IEnumerable<Bier> GetBieren()
            {
                return _bierRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(b => b.Naam);
            }

            [HttpGet("{id}")]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            public ActionResult<Bier> GetBier(int id)
            {
                Bier bier = _bierRepository.GetBy(id);
                if (bier == null)
                    return NotFound();
                return bier;
            }

            [HttpPost]
            [Authorize(Roles = "Brouwer, Admin")]
            public IActionResult PostBier(Bier bier)
            {
                Brouwer brouwer = _brouwerRepository.GetBy(User.Identity.Name);
                brouwer.AddBier(bier);
                _brouwerRepository.SaveChanges();
                return NoContent();
            }
```

Any help is appreciated, if anyone could help, seeing some extra code I'm happy to provide it.
[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: If changing `[Authorize(Roles = "Brouwer, Admin")]` to `[Authorize()]`, will you receive `401`? What is the header you passed to server?

Comment: your token has been expired, just try to clear your cache and logout and login again and see if it works!